# GeoNear indexes - create indexes

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to create index on my mongoDB and I get this error "unable to find index for $geonear query",
I tried to do the following -
"db.collection.createIndex({location: '2d'})"
"db.collection.ensureIndex({location: '2d'})"

in my DB its order in that way:

```
{ location: [30,30] }
```

It works on my local computer but on my EC2 it is not work, I don't know if it because I did something before on my local computer ..

Comment: I think you need to add a few more details, like the error you are getting and maybe a larger piece of code.